# Select rows based on field values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have this structure

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    Field1   VARCHAR(10),
    Field2   VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT #Test VALUES('AAA','NO'),
                   ('BBB','NO'),
                   ('BBB','YES'),
                   ('BBB','SURE'),
                   ('CCC','NO'),
                   ('DDD','NO'),
                   ('DDD','YES'),
                   ('DDD','ALWAYS')

SELECT * FROM #Test
```

Every distinct `Field1` value has `Field2` 'NO'. 
I want to select all rows from `#Test` such that if distinct `Field1` value has multiple `Field2` values, return everything except the row with `Field2`='NO', otherwise return with 'NO' value. 
So result should be this

[image]

AAA has only 'NO', so we return it, BBB has multiple, so return everything except 'NO'.

I want to select it in one statement, without deleting , etc.. I tried `ROW_NUMBER()` partitioned by `Field1`, but that doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT * FROM #Test t
WHERE t.Field2 <> 'NO'
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Test WHERE Field1 = t.Field1 AND Field2 <> 'NO')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a856be2b612ea384733739da9f3e4823).
Results:

```
> Field1 | Field2
> :----- | :-----
> AAA    | NO    
> BBB    | YES   
> BBB    | SURE  
> CCC    | NO    
> DDD    | YES   
> DDD    | ALWAYS
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example helps you.

```
select Field1,Field2 from #Test where Field1 not in(SELECT Field1 FROM #Test where Field2<>'NO')
UNION ALL
SELECT Field1,Field2 FROM #Test where Field2<>'NO'
order by Field1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function :

```
SELECT t.Field1, t.Field2 
FROM (SELECT t.*, 
             SUM(CASE WHEN FIELD2 = 'NO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY FIELD1) AS NO_FLAG,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY FIELD1) AS CNT
      FROM Test t
      ) t
WHERE (CNT <> NO_FLAG AND FIELD2 <> 'NO') OR
      (CNT = NO_FLAG AND FIELD2 = 'NO');
```

Here is [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b8d56/1).